# Setting SQL Query equal to an Array

Tags: php, mysql

I am doing a query as follows

```
select id, prefix, fname, lname, suffix, city, state, zip, bio, votes from stateChair_nominees where id=$candidate_id
```

My candidate id is equal to the post method.

```
$candidate_id = $_POST;
```

I keep getting this error..

select id, prefix, fname, lname, suffix, city, state, zip, bio, votes from stateChair_nominees where id=Array" Invalid query1Unknown column 'Array' in 'where clause

I am getting the invalid query1 error because it goes to that on a die

```
$result_candidate = mysql_query($sql_candidate, $link) or die("Invalid query1". mysql_error());
```

Why is my id saying equal to array?

```
where id=Array"
```

I want my sql statement to be equal to each id upon the vote. How do I get my query to do this?

Thanks :)

Comment: If you wonder why it writes array try this: $a=array(); echo "\$a = $a";

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`$_POST` is an array of all values passed via POST. If you're submitting a form containing an input element with name 'id', like this,

```
`<input name="id" value="Your_ID_Here" />`
```

you would use `$_POST['id']`.

Also, your query is vulnerable to SQL injection. Escape with that value with `mysql_real_escape_string()` or use prepared statements ([mysqli](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.prepare.php) or [PDO](http://php.net/manual/en/pdo.prepare.php)).

Comment: So if I wanted to do keys say 1, 2, and 3 how would the $_POST look?

$_POST[1]

How would I put the other id's in there?

Comment: `$_POST` is an associative array. It has strings as keys. The array keys will be the `name` properties you gave to the form elements.

Answer (score 0):

$_POST is an array containing the entire form as received in the request.  It might help you to view

```
print_r($_POST);
```

You will want to reference the actual form variable name, for example:

```
$candidate_id = $_POST['id'];
```

If you are expecting an array of id's, your sql will need to use the `IN` clause and `implode` the id array.

```
$candidate_ids = $_POST['id'];

/* escape $candidate_ids here, you can use array_walk for this */

$sql = 'select ... where candidate_id in (' . implode(',', $candidate_ids) . ')';
```

Make sure you are properly [escaping](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-real-escape-string.php) your dynamic sql as well.

Comment: What if the name element on the form is equal to a variable?

For instance..my checkbox is equal to a variable that is equal to a certain row in my database. basically $candidate is equal to either 1,2 or 3 or 4..so on.

So if I don't have a name to reference on my 

$candidate_id = $_POST[1]; 

Then how do I pull all those id's into my logic?

Comment: print "<td width=\"4\" valign=\"top\"><input type=\"checkbox\" name=$candidate id=\"candidate\" value=$id></td>";

Thats the button on my other form.